# X new questions with activity on SO

Tags: support, live-refresh

I noticed that clickable box showing up on Meta-SO "X new questions with activity".
On click, it displays the concerned questions.

But, if I'm not wrong, I never saw this on SO before.
I guess it's because there is a lot more activity on SO, and "67 new questions with activity" wouldn't be that good.

Yet, is there any way to activate it on SO ?

And if not, wouldn't be useful to add such a feature for the "interesting" tab only, which is more likely to have less activity ?

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Live refresh has been around for a long time, but is explicitly disabled on the Stack Overflow front pages (including *interesting*) as the number of new posts per minute would be far too great.

As such, you'll *only* see this on tag pages (including combined tag searches).

See [New Feature: real time updates to questions, answers, and inbox](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125677/new-feature-real-time-updates-to-questions-answers-and-inbox)

> Stack Overflow has a massive amount of activity so we have decided to limit this feature to tags only. Both the "newest" and "active" tab will have updates after first selecting a tag or tag combination.

Answer (score 2):

You can see the live refresh on individual tag pages on Stack Overflow:

[image]