# Questions with ignored tags are hidden on the homepage even if the "gray out" option is selected

Tags: bug, status-review, homepage, ignored-tags

This appears to be a problem on the main site only (I couldn't repro here or on Meta Stack Exchange).

Steps to reproduce:

1. Find a popular tag that has some questions displayed **on the homepage**.
2. Add that tag to your ignored tags and make sure the "gray out" option is selected.
3. Reload the page.

Once the tag is added to the ignored tags, relevant questions will be grayed out normally<sup>1</sup> but after the page is reloaded, they will all be gone.

Here's a demo:

[image]

---

<sup>1</sup> <sub>Well, not exactly normally. They used to be displayed in lower opacity but I have a [separate post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/375640/348196) about that.</sub>

Comment: Possibly related: [New CSS class on landing page exposes tag regex issue](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/415619/8967612).

Comment: I was able to reproduce this on Math, so it seems to be a general issue. I'll see if I can figure out what's going on.

Comment: OK... now I'm kinda confused. I know that people have been able to see ignored questions for a while because they've posted lots of screenshots about it... so what I'm experiencing seems new... this bug is 6 months old, though?

Comment: @Catija Yes, it's at least 7+ months old (I didn't try to use ignored tags on SO before that so it could be way older). As mentioned above though, I could not reproduce this on MSO, MSE, or on stackoverflow.com/questions.

Comment: It just... feels like it has to be related to site volume. SO and Math are the two highest-volume sites on the network... but that may just be... some sort of low sample size issue?

Comment: @Catija Could be related to site volume. I know that live refresh is disabled on SO's home page (edit: [ref](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/265788/8967612)). Could it be related to that? I don't use Math, so I don't know if it's disabled there but I left its homepage open for a few minutes and didn't get any updates. Do you know if it's disabled there?

Comment: It's definitely not updating on Math, so it seems like it's likely disabled there, too... but I can't find a site setting, which means it may be hard coded somewhere... which means ... maybe there is an odd correlation between these two...